# React query или RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux

По вакансиям и поиску в интернете сложно понять, что лучше изучать: React query или RTK query. Либо нужно то и другое. Либо можно без этого.

Может есть более-менее четкий критерий, чтобы определиться с выбором?

Comment: Лучше знать и то и то, чем не знать ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему это довольно холиварная тема. Будет множество сторонников той или иной технологии, но они очень похожи. Я могу вывести такой критерий выбора:

- Если Вы уже используете Redux Toolkit в своих проектах - то будет логичнее использовать RTK Query, так как, насколько я понимаю, он уже скачивается с Redux Toolkit, не зависимо от того, будете Вы его использовать или нет. Плюс он хорошо интегрирован в работу с редаксом. Это, как мне кажется, логичное решение, если Вы используете редакс.
- Если редакс не используете, можете попробовать React query.

Они очень похожи, и что то мне подсказывает, что разработчики этих продуктов смотрят друг на друга, и вводят новые фишки противоположной библиотеки и себе.

Как я уже писал - это холиварная тема, если в одной компании используют уже React Query, то его скорее всего и будут использовать, а пользователи RTK Query будут топить за свой выбор. Если не можете выбрать, то руководствуйтесь, хотя бы для начала, принципом "использую редакс, логичнее использовать RTK Query", и на против.

Можете подробнее почитать хорошую статью:
https://www.frontendmag.com/insights/react-query-vs-rtk-query/

Comment: Только вчера пришел к точно такому же заключению, спасибо за ответ